# Symfony validator does not validate post data

Tags: symfony

I am moving to Symfony and have the problem with validation of post data that I am sending. I have followed official docs and put in Entity this property:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)   
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      min = 3,
 *      max = 50,
 *      minMessage = "Your name must be at least {{ limit }} characters long",
 *      maxMessage = "Your name cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters"
 * )
 */
private $name;
```

Code in controller is:

```
    $student = new Student();
    $student->setName($request->query->get('name'));
    $student->setBirth_Date( new \DateTime($request->query->get('date') ) );

    $validator = $this->get('validator');
    $errors = $validator->validate($student);

    if (count($errors) > 0) {
        /*
         * Uses a __toString method on the $errors variable which is a
         * ConstraintViolationList object. This gives us a nice string
         * for debugging.
         */
        $errorsString = (string) $errors;

        return new Response('Validation errors: '. $errorsString);
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($student);

    // actually executes the queries (i.e. the INSERT query)
    $em->flush();

    return new Response('Saved new student with id '. $student->getId());
```

Why it is not validating and I always get new entry in database? Am I missing something?

Comment: Try to send some invalid data, and put var_dump($student); var_dump($errors); die(); after line '$errors = $validator->validate($student);'

And please paste results in your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check thats you configure validation annotation constrait, read this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#configuration
And clear cache

```
app/console cache:clear
```

or for symfony3

```
bin/console cache:clear
```

Comment: maybe you forget namespace add 'use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;'  to Entity.
i tried your code and its worked

Comment: no, i have that line..just cannot get validator in controller. Is there another way to load validator? when I write $validator variable to logs, i get empty array

Comment: Try: use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation; $validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()->enableAnnotationMappin‌​g()->getValidator();

Comment: Attempted to call an undefined method named "enableAnnotationMappin‌​‌​g" of class "Symfony\Component\Validator\ValidatorBuilder"

Comment: Example from official doc http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/validator/resources.html#the-annotationloader. At github method exists too https://github.com/symfony/validator/blob/master/ValidatorBuilder.php. Which version of symfony you use?

Comment: I see.. but i don't understand what I am missing. Should i do some update of Entity, when I added Annotations?

Answer (score 0):

Had to put     `validation: { enabled: true, enable_annotations: false  }` in config. Didn't found this in the docs.
Also Assert NotBlank() before Length is needed for second validation to take place.

```
   /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 3,
     *      max = 50,
     *      minMessage = "Your name must be at least {{ limit }} characters long",
     *      maxMessage = "Your name cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters"
     * )
     */
```